# How to log request xmls in resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am using spring with jaxb. I am using exchange method to post the requests. I want to log the requests. How can I do it?

Comment: More details required!!

Comment: restTemplateObj.exchange(updateUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class,profileParam);
I want to log the exact request xml that is posted to the url

Answer (score -1):

`org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor`

"preHandle" method

```
IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream())
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate this answer.?